# Getting triplet characters from strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

Define the `get_triples_dict()` function which is passed a string of text
as a parameter. The function first converts the parameter string to
lower case and then returns a dictionary with keys which are all the
unique consecutive three alphabetic characters from the text, and the
corresponding values are the number of times the three consecutive
alphabetic characters appear in the text. Use the `isalpha()` method to
check if a character is alphabetic or not. The dictionary should only
contain entries which occur more than once.  After your dictionary has
been created and populated, you need to remove any key-value pairs which
have a corresponding value of `1`.

I need help with coding this `get_triples_dict` function:

```
def get_triples_dict(text):


def test_get_triples_dict():
    print("1.")
    print_dict_in_key_order(get_triples_dict('super, duper'))
    print("\n2.")
    print_dict_in_key_order(get_triples_dict("ABC ABC ABC"))
    print("\n3.")
    print_dict_in_key_order(get_triples_dict("Sometimes the smallest things make more room in your heart"))
    print("\n4.")
    print_dict_in_key_order(get_triples_dict("My favourite painting is the painting i did of my dog in that painting in my den"))
```

[image: Expected output]

Comment: Do you have an [attempted solution](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Start by iterating over the string in with a span of 3 and put that into the dict, then increment each time you see it again

Comment: yeah sorry i don't have an attempted solution

Comment: I know this is being stingy but i was hoping someone could help me code that function

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to complete your assignment for you, but below is a good start to what you need to do. I believe you can write the code that sorts the words and prints out the dictionary. Make sure to study each line and then once you get the general idea, write your own version.

```
def get_triples_dict(text):
    d = dict()
    text = text.lower().replace(' ', '') # set to lowercase and remove spaces
    for i in range(len(text) - 2): # stops early to prevent index out of bounds exception
        bit = text[i: i + 3] # characters in groups of 3
        if all(c.isalpha() for c in bit): # all characters must be alphabetic
            if not bit in d: # if there's no entry
                d[bit] = 0
            d[bit] += 1
    copy = d.copy() # we cannot remove items from a list we are looping over (concurrent modification exception)
    for key, value in copy.items():
        if value == 1: # remove items with counts of 1
            d.pop(key)
    return d
```