# get triplets from a string of text

Tags: python, python-3.x

Define the `get_triples_dict()` function which is passed a string of text
as a parameter. The function first converts the parameter string to
lower case and then returns a dictionary with keys which are all the
unique consecutive three alphabetic characters from the text, and the
corresponding values are the number of times the three consecutive
alphabetic characters appear in the text. Use the `isalpha()` method to
check if a character is alphabetic or not. The dictionary should only
contain entries which occur more than once.  After your dictionary has
been created and populated, you need to remove any key-value pairs which
have a corresponding value of 1.

can someone help me fix my code so that i can get the right output? i have attempted it but it doesn't exactly work. i just need some help with the `get_triples_dict` function, i don't need to touch the `test_get_triples_dict` function. below is what i have so far along with the expected output:

```
def get_triples_dict(text):

       triples_dict = {}

       word = ""

       mod_text = ""

       # convert the text to contain only letters and convert all letters to lowercase

       for i in range(0,len(text)):

                      if text[i].isalpha():

                                     mod_text = mod_text + text[i].lower()

       # if length of text >= 3 letters                     

       if(len(mod_text) >= 3):

                      # loop over the text

                      for i in range(0,len(mod_text)-2):

                                     word = mod_text[i:i+3] # extract 3 letter word from starting with the letter at i

                                     if word in triples_dict.keys(): # if word is in dictionary then increment its frequency

                                                    triples_dict[word] = triples_dict[word] + 1

                                     else: # else insert the word in dictionary with frequency 1

                                                    triples_dict[word] = 1



       keys = triples_dict.keys() # get the list of keys in the dictionary

       # loop over the keys list

       for i in range(0,len(keys)):

                      if triples_dict[keys] == 1: #if frequency of the word is 1, then remove the entry from dictionary

                                     del triples_dict[keys]
                                     i = i - 1 # decrement i

       return triples_dict # return the dictionary


def test_get_triples_dict():
    print("1.")
    print_dict_in_key_order(get_triples_dict('super, duper'))
    print("\n2.")
    print_dict_in_key_order(get_triples_dict("ABC ABC ABC"))
    print("\n3.")
    print_dict_in_key_order(get_triples_dict("Sometimes the smallest things make more room in your heart"))
    print("\n4.")
    print_dict_in_key_order(get_triples_dict("My favourite painting is the painting i did of my dog in that painting in my den"))
```

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve]. This means pinpointing the exact problem you are facing and constructing a **minimal** example (usually a few lines) to demonstrate the problem. Good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting triplet characters from strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50422077/getting-triplet-characters-from-strings)